# when i click on prev it skip one section and goes to another

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I have 5 sections in my slider. When I click next it works fine, but when I click prev it skips one slide and goes to another; only first time, if I click second time it works fine. Ex: I have 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 section, I'm on 3rd section, if I click prev it goes to 1 not 2.

```
var slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
var corousel = document.querySelector('.corousel');
var next = document.querySelector('.next');
var prev = document.querySelector('.prev');

var direction=-1;
console.log(direction);

next.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // if (direction === 1) {
    //     slider.prepend(slider.lastElementChild);
    // }
    direction = -1;
    corousel.style.justifyContent = 'flex-start';
    slider.style.transform = 'translate(-20%)';
});
prev.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // if (direction === -1) {
    //     slider.appendChild(slider.firstElementChild);
    // } 
    direction = 1;
    corousel.style.justifyContent = 'flex-end';
    slider.style.transform = 'translate(20%)';
    slider.style.marginRight = "-60px";
});
slider.addEventListener('transitionend', function () {
    if (direction === 1) {
        slider.prepend(slider.lastElementChild);
    } else {
        slider.appendChild(slider.firstElementChild);
    }
    slider.style.transition = 'none';
    slider.style.transform = 'translate(0)';
    setTimeout(() = > {
        slider.style.transition = 'all 0.5s';
    })
}, false);
```

Comment: i think it has to do something with css i think

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] by adding the HTML and CSS? Use [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: please share html as well

Comment: thanks for commenting but i got it the transitionEnd event was running twice on transform transition and on margin-right i just added a if condition to run code only on transform property